# how to override woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am newbie to wordpress and woocommerce. I have to change

```
<ul class="products"> to <div class="myclass">.
```

For that I just coppied plugins/woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php in mytheme/woocommerce/loop/loop-start.php and changed the file loop-start.php accordingly. But this change does not apply to shop page of my theme. Any help will be appriciated.

Thanks in advance,

Aisha

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just tested Below solutions for you, It worked.

Copy loop-shop.php file from

> wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\loop-shop.php

and past it on your theme at

> yourtheme\woocommerce\loop-shop.php

Find with `<ul class="products"> code </ul>` and replaced with `<div class="myclass"> code </div>`

Comment: Best to do this and then also change the `<li>` and `</li>` in `woocommerce/templates/content-product.php` otherwise some browsers may still render the loop as a `<ul>`.

Answer (score 8):

Since **WooCommerce 2.0.0** a `loop-start.php` file was introduced. This file will need to be changed in order to update your class in the product loop.

```
wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\loop\loop-start.php
```

and past it on your theme at

```
yourtheme\woocommerce\loop\loop-start.php
```

Comment: Correct, and do not forget loop-end.php as it contains a closing </ul>